# PHP Query to Get SUM of Amount per user between dates

Tags: php, sql-server, database, mysqli

I have a database setup where it saves data of a sales person who has collected a certain amount of money and has his commission there as well.

```
 Example:
 Date        Name    Amount Sold   Commission Earned
 2013-2-3   John A     100.00          20.00
 2013-2-3   Amy W      200.00          40.00
 2013-2-3   John A     230.00          46.00
 2013-2-2   John A     300.00          60.00
 2013-2-2   Bill B     400.00          80.00
 Etc....
```

I am trying to show the top sales person by commission earned for the entire week. I need to somehow query the database to find all of the commissions for the week, then group them and Sum the total earned and display the top earner for the week.

This is what I have so far and it works but it shows all of the earnings made last week in rows. I just don't know how to group them by their name and then add the commissions together then display them from the sales person who made the most.

```
   require_once('connectvars.php');
   $dbc = mysqli_connect(CDB_HOST, CDB_USER, CDB_PASSWORD, CDB_NAME);
   // GET COLLECTOR INFO
   $query = "SELECT * FROM commissioninfo WHERE thedate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY 
   AND thedate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY ORDER BY amountoffeeearned DESC"; 
   $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>' . $row['salesperson'] . '</td>';
         echo ' <td>' . $row['amountoffeeearned'] . '</td>';
         echo '</tr>';                              
      }
      mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `Name` in `Group by` then `Sum` the `Amount Sold` you will get the total Sum of `Amount Sold` per `user`. Something like this.

```
SELECT   NAME, 
         Sum(`Amount Sold`)     sum_amount , 
         sum(`commission earned`) sum_comm 
FROM     commissioninfo 
WHERE    thedate >= curdate() - interval dayofweek(curdate())+6 day 
AND      thedate < curdate()  - interval dayofweek(curdate())-1 day 
GROUP BY NAME 
ORDER BY sum_amount DESC
```

Update :

```
SELECT salesperson, 
       Sum(amountcollected) 
FROM   commissioninfo 
WHERE  thedate >= Curdate() - INTERVAL Dayofweek(Curdate())+6 day 
       AND thedate < Curdate() - INTERVAL Dayofweek(Curdate())-1 day 
GROUP  BY salesperson
```

Comment: Ok So here is what I tried and It did group all of the names perfectly, but they all say 0 where the totalsum is being displayed.     SELECT salesperson, SUM('amountcollected') as 'totalsum' FROM commissioninfo WHERE thedate >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND thedate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY GROUP BY salesperson ORDER BY amountcollected DESC

Comment: I am also using $row['totalsum'] where the total is suppose to show.

Comment: @user2593041 are you sure that each `salesperson` have `amountcollected` with in that period

Comment: Let me check real quick

Comment: Even when I use this query in the PHPMyAdmin, I am getting 0's in the amount                    SELECT collector, SUM('amountcollected') as 'totalsum' FROM commissioninfo GROUP BY collector ORDER BY totalsum DESC

Comment: @user2593041 what happens when you run this `SELECT salesperson,amountcollected 
FROM commissioninfo 
WHERE thedate >= Curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY 
AND thedate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY ` check whether you have data in `amountcollected`

Comment: I get the totals and the names of the salesperson next to each. The only difference is that they are not totaled or grouped.

Comment: It was a syntax error ------> This works  SELECT salesperson, SUM(amountcollected) as 'totalsum' FROM commissioninfo WHERE thedate >= Curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY AND thedate < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY GROUP BY salesperson

Comment: Just checked for best answer! Thanks again!

Comment: How would I use this code but set the start day of the week from Thursday to Wednesday?

Comment: @user2593041 - ask it as a new question

Comment: Sorry it won't let me. I guess I am over my limit or something.

Answer (score 0):

Add Name in Group By and SUM([Commission Earned]) in Order By DESC.

**Or**

Try this:

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM([Amount Sold]) as WeekAmountSold,
       SUM([Commission Earned]) as WeekCommissionEarned 
FROM commissioninfo 
WHERE Date >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-7) DAY) 
      AND Date < DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(curdate())) DAY) 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY SUM([Commission Earned]) DESC
```

Comment: How would I use this code but set the start day of the week from Thursday to Wednesday?